# Number of Nodes within a Given Distance from a Node

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Suppose we are given a $d$-regular graph $G=(V,E)$ of order $n$. 
Let $\lambda_2$  be the second-largest eigenvalue of $G$'s adjacency matrix.
Does this information help obtaining a lowerbound or upperbound on the number of nodes within a distance at most $k$ from an arbitrary node $v$?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by normalized adjacency matrix.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil, I'll just edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: The problem is that if $\lambda_2$ is small relative to $\lambda_1$, our graph is some sort of expander and, at least for moderate values of $k$, I'd expect the number of vertices at distance $k$ to be larger. In other words I'd expect to get a lower bound, not an upper bound.

Comment: That sounds quite convincing, thank you @ChrisGodsil. A lowerbound would be interesting for my application as well. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: The book "Spectral Graph theory" by Fan Chung (the first chapters are avaiable online through her homepage) contains some such bounds, e.g. $\max_{i \not = 1} |\lambda_i| \geq \sqrt{\frac{n-d}{(n-1)d}}$.